# JavaScript / HTML - refer to a containing li-element from a a-element inside it

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have some list-elements of which each contains an `<a>`-element:

```
    <li class="invis article notCart" id="Waschmaschine">
      <div class="articleDetails">
        ...stuff...
      </div>
      <a onclick="intoCart(this);" class="intoCart">
        In den Warenkorb</a>
    </li>
```

I want to refer to the li-element itself in this line:

```
<a onclick="intoCart(this);"
```

Of course `this`doesn't work, it refers to the text inside `<a>`.
Is it possible to do this without using the ID of `<li>`, since the `<a>`is within it?

I have many of such list elements and dont want to have to refer to every one of them through IDs.

Comment: `this.parentNode` do you mean?

Comment: Couldn't you use `this.parentElement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is to use:

```
<a onclick="intoCart(this.parentNode);"
```

Though this is a fragile solution, inevitably requiring knowledge of the DOM constructed from the HTML.

You could, of course, simply pass `this` to the function as you were, but find the relevant `parentNode` within the function itself.

References:

- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I was somehow confused and thought it must be some special HTML tag and not js command, since it's in the HTML-code.

Thanks for the quick help

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, and I have no idea why you're apologising; I'm just glad to have been of help to you! =)